# Can we use two queries in Single start method in apex batch class?

Tags: apex

I have two objects (**Object A** and **Object B**). There is no relationship between two objects. In object A, I have 2 text fields: **UserId** and **User Name**. I want to update the full name in the User Name field by referring to the value from Object B (**Name** field). The issue is that ObjectB gets up to 50k records only where the actual count is more than 100k records. I am unsure whether using two Database.getQueryLocator is the best practice within the start method. Since Object A has more than 30 million records. I need to filter out the Object A records based on values available in Object B. Please let me know if you have answers to my queries.

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
  List<ObjectB>  objBList = [SELECT Id,Name, User_ID_c FROM ObjectB WHERE User_ID__c != null];
  Map<String,String> objMap = new Map<String,String>();
  for(ObjectA objB: objAList){
    objMap.put(objB.User_ID_Network__c, objB.Name);
  } 

  String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, UserId__c, User_Name__c FROM ObjectA WHERE UserId__c IN :objMap.keyset() AND UserId__c != NULL AND User_Name__c  = null'

  return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

Comment: You do, of course, have an indirect relationship between the two: the `User` (I've assumed that `UserId__c` and `User_ID__c` are both lookup to `User`). I would consider switching the batch to run on `User`, using the related list relationships to get the As and Bs associated with it that match specific criteria.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for the reply. By the way, the **User_ID_Network__c** value in object B is updated from the integration side. Hence the user_Id_Network is completely different from the userId from the User object. Also, both **user_Id_Networ__c** and **userId__c** are the text field